# mod_rewrite to pass date to file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file `http://sub.domain.com/apush/noteGetter.php` that handles dates in the format `d-m-y` through `noteGetter.php?date=d-m-y`. For example, I'll use January 13th, 2017. I want the url to be `http://sub.domain.com/apush/notes/2017/01/13`. I know this can be accomplished using mod_rewrite through htaccess, but I have little experience with regular expressions and even less with htaccess. What rules and conditions would I need to add to get this URL rewritten?

**Update**

Current 'apush' directory `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^notes/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})$ "noteGetter.php?date=$3-$2-$1"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
DirectoryIndex home.php
ErrorDocument 404 'https://www.domain.com/404'
```

Current 'root' directory `.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/tsenter/sub.domain.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Members Area"
require valid-user
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^notes/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})$ "noteGetter.php?date=$3-$2-$1"
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex home.php
ErrorDocument 404 'https://www.domain.com/404'
```

**Update 2**

New 'apush' directory `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^notes/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})$ "noteGetter.php?date=$3-$2-$1"
```

New 'root' directory `.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/tsenter/sub.domain.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Members Area"
require valid-user
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex home.php
ErrorDocument 404 'https://www.domain.com/404'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from discussion you are looking to place the rules in a `.htaccess` file in your `apush` directory. You would need this in your `apush` `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^notes/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})$ "noteGetter.php?date=$3-$2-$1"
```

This is a simple matching of any four numbers for year, any two numbers for month, any two numbers for day. Simplest to do the verification in your script and have a simple regex here.

Comment: For what I'm doing, I have the domain `sub.domain.com/apush/notes/y/m/d` that should be rewritten to `sub.domain.com/apush/noteGetter?date=m-d-y`, and this for some reason doesn't work for me. The current `.htaccess` file for the `apush` directory has been added to the question

Comment: I updated my answer with a drop-in replacement for your `.htaccess` file in `apush`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but for some reason it's still redirecting me to the 404 page. I was trying `sub.domain.com/apush/notes/2017/01/07`, which redirects me to `domain.com/404`. I have verified that the file at `sub.domain.com/apush/noteGetter.php` is valid. I do have an `.htaccess` in about every directory, so I don't know if that's the issue or not.

Comment: Yes it probably is. Please post your root `.htaccess` file as that is the other one that will affect this.

Comment: Well that's the problem, the code is written for your apush .htaccess, not your root one, as that's where you said you were putting it. Put the code in my answer in your apush .htaccess and take it out of your root one.

Comment: Also no need to duplicate any of the rest of it in your apush one. Put my answer in apush and the rest in root only.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been messing around with the `.htaccess` files last night and forgot to delete those chunks. I also just realized my autouploader wasn't working properly, so that didn't help. Thank you for your patience and time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135191/discussion-between-zonalyewhd-and-superduperapps).